# WordPress installation on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

I am new in Ubuntu. Recently I am using Ubuntu 12.10. When I used window xp I used WordPress in XAMPP. The installation press of WordPress in windows xp on XAMPP is very simple, only copy the downloaded WordPress file on 'htdocs' folder and change some come on 'wpconfig.php', then ready to use. Now in Ubuntu 12.10, I using LAMPP, do the same process as windows xp but don't works.

Any suggestion ...

Comment: What exactly are you trying?   Are you installing into the /var/www directory?

Comment: I already install LAMPP 1.8.1 so I want to install wordpress inside the LAMPP.

Comment: LAMP refers to Linux Apache MySQL and PHP.  If that's the case, you can downlowd the latest version of Wordpress, and untar/unzip it in the /var/www directory and you're done.  If you are doing this command line, you can navigate like so `cd /var/www` and then use wget like so `wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz`  And then run `tar -xzvf latest.tar.gz`

Comment: Can you explain me more because of my lack of experience in Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First copy the downloaded WordPress file and paste it into desktop. The downloaded file name is assume that as 'latest.tar.gz'

### Then open 'terminal' and write

```
 cd Desktop
```

### Now type

```
sudo tar -xzvf latest.tar.gz
```

that unpacked the downloaded file into original file

### now type

```
sudo mv wordpress /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

that move the 'wordpress' file into 
   /opt/lampp/htdocs

### Now we done.

Answer (score 3):

1) Run the Application "Terminal"

Type the following:

```
cd /var/www
```

You are now in what used to be `htdocs` for XAMP

2) Now type the following:

```
sudo wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
```

You should be able to watch Ubuntu connect and download wordpress.

3) Once downloaded type this:

```
ls
```

You should see a file called `latest.tar.gz` in there.

4) type the following:

```
tar -xzvf latest.tar.gz
```

This command will unpack the compressed file you just downloaded.

5) type this again:

```
ls
```

You should see a directory called "wordpress".

You will now be able to access your wordpress installation by going to

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: There in an error in step 4. " Cannot open: No such file or directory " This type of msg show many.

Comment: attempt `sudo tar -xzvf latest.tar.gz`

Comment: I updated/edited my answer.  I just performed all commands on a test server and they ran flawlessly.  You can right-click and copy the command and then right-click paste them into terminal

Comment: In step 6 a new error msg appear :  " mv: invalid option -- 'R'
Try `mv --help' for more information. "

Comment: First I apologize. When I try to start my LAMPP then it says another apache is running. Then I try "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php", but some error msg appear in that page such as " Error: PHP is not running " and many more

Comment: You may have to adjust your wp config file to your system settings, or make sure you have met certain criteria ..  Things such as CURL, GD and EXIF will need to be installed.  They are all installed using `sudo apt-get install YOURAPP`  ...  A list of what wordpress needs can be found on this thread http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42098/what-are-php-extensions-and-libraries-wp-needs-and-or-uses

Comment: I just add the following command " sudo mv wordpress /opt/lampp/htdocs " and it works fine that I wanted. Thanks for everything

Answer (score 0):

I found a great tutorial on installing WordPress on Ubuntu servers here http://development.solepop.com/setting-up-wordpress-on-ubuntu/.

Prerequisites:

You should have a bare-bones Ubuntu server from a hosting provider of your choice with root access. You should also have your domain mapped to the IP address of your server through DNS.

Step 1.  Make sure your box has the lamp stack installed. Login as a root user in your server box and first update the packages with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then install lamp server:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

** Make sure you have the (^) at the end

You will be prompted to provide a mysql password for the root user. Go ahead and type it in and confirm the password in the next screen.

Step 2. Setup your mysql database

```
mysql -u root -p
```

You will be prompted to give your password. Insert the password that you specified from Step 1. You will then have access to the MySQL command line where you can create a MySQL database and user:

```
CREATE DATABASE wordpressblog;
CREATE USER wordpressblog@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '<set a password for the new database user>';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpressblog.* TO wordpressblog@localhost;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
```

Step 3. Type in the following in order (make sure to replace  with your domain address which in our case is solepop.com):

```
mkdir -p /srv/www/<your domain>/src/
mkdir -p /srv/www/<your domain>/public_html/
cd /srv/www/<your domain>/src/
wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
tar -zxvf /srv/www/<your domain>/src/latest.tar.gz
cp -R /srv/www/<your domain>/src/wordpress/* /srv/www/<your domain>/public_html/
rm -rf /srv/www/<your domain>/src/wordpress/
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/www/<your domain>/public_html
```

Pretty much what we did here was that we created a src folder where we downloaded the latest version of WordPress. After unzipping the installation in our src folder, we then copied all the contents from the src folder to our public_html folder.  After we copied all the contents we then deleted the downloaded WordPress files from the src folder. Lastly, we gave apache the ownership of the public_html folder.

Step 4. Give the public_html folder and files the proper permissions:

```
find /srv/www/<your domain>/public_html -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
find /srv/www/<your domain>/public_html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

Step 5.  Go to your sites-enabled folder in apache2.

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

Step 6. Erase all the contents in the 000-default.conf file and type the following (insert your domain name for all the  areas):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that

# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating

# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName

# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to

# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this

# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.

# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

ServerName <your domain>

<Directory />
 AllowOverride all
 Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot /srv/www/<your domain>/public_html/

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,

# error, crit, alert, emerg.

# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular

# modules, e.g.

#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are

# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to

# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the

# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only

# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".

#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

</VirtualHost>
```

Step 7. Enable mod rewrite (important for permalinks to work) and restart apache.

```
 a2enmod rewrite
 service apache2 restart
```

Step 8. Go to your domain from the browser.

Click Let’s Go

[step 1 http://www.solepop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Screen-Shot-2015-01-12-at-4.37.52-PM.png](http://www.solepop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Screen-Shot-2015-01-12-at-4.37.52-PM.png)

Fill the database information from Step 2.

[step 2 http://www.solepop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Screenii-Shot-2015-01-12-at-4.42.06-PM.png](http://www.solepop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Screenii-Shot-2015-01-12-at-4.42.06-PM.png)

Click Run the install.

[step 3 http://www.solepop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Screen-Shot-2015-01-12-at-4.42.24-PM.png](http://www.solepop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Screen-Shot-2015-01-12-at-4.42.24-PM.png)

Fill out basic info about your blog.

[step 4 http://www.solepop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Screen-Shot-2015-01-12-at-4.42.39-PM.png](http://www.solepop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Screen-Shot-2015-01-12-at-4.42.39-PM.png)

Installation complete…

[step 5 http://www.solepop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Screen-Shot-2015-01-12-at-8.27.38-PM.png](http://www.solepop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Screen-Shot-2015-01-12-at-8.27.38-PM.png)

After installation, visit your domain on your browser and you should see your WordPress blog.

[step 6 http://www.solepop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Screen-Shot-2015-01-12-at-8.27.53-PM.png](http://www.solepop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Screen-Shot-2015-01-12-at-8.27.53-PM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following links, if you want to install the wordpress on Ubuntu:

- [Manually](https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/how-to-install-wordpress-in-ubuntu-server-12-04-lts/)
- [Shell Script](https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/automated-installation-of-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-server/)
- [Ansible](https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2015/02/25/installing-the-wordpress-on-ubuntu-using-ansible/)

Hopy this will help you. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

[Process of installation of WordPress in Ubuntu](https://www.znetlive.com/blog/how-to-install-wordpress-in-ubuntu/):

> 1. Installing the web server: Web server is the front end which we use to serve web pages on a web browser. We will install the Apache2 as
>      webserver on our server.
> 2. Setting up MySQL service: MySQL is the database which will be used to store our data. Another option is use Maria DB. But since we have
>      chosen MySQL.
> 3. Install PHP and its modules  After installing all the above servers and packages, Ubuntu server is now ready to host WordPress.
> 4. Download the WordPress in /var/www/html/ and extract it.
> 5. This is the last step to configure WordPress.

Comment: All text from this answer is copied from that link; try to write your own answer, instead of copying other people's content.